# How to make WordPress style.css work as a Stylus .styl -file

Tags: css, wordpress, stylus, codekit

I'm running into problems with WordPress style.css files when trying to use then as .styl -files. The style.css from *twentytwelve* is the only one so far that works when I just change it from .css to .styl.

So for example when I copy-paste the style.css from theme *twentyeleven* or *Nimble* by ElegantThemes to a .styl -file, it won't compile and I get an error from CodeKit:

```
ParseError: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/style.styl:1454
   1450| }
   1451| article.feature-image.small .entry-summary p a {
   1452|   background: #222;
   1453|   color: #eee;
 > 1454|   display: block;
   1455|   left: -23.8%;
   1456|   padding: 9px 26px 9px 85px;
   1457|   position: relative;

expected "indent", got ";"
```

If I delete all the CSS from around it, the error just jumps to a different line of code.
I also get similar errors if I use css2stylus.com to make Stylus from CSS.

**So for you people wiser than me:**

1. How would one go about debugging Stylus? Is there a smart method for that? What if it's just copy-pasted CSS, and what if it's been compiled to .styl?
2. Any way to just make the style.css -files work by not compiling, other than loading separate files using one made with Stylus and the original CSS?
3. Do you think that this kind of problems are less likely to happen with i.e. SASS?

So for anyone using Stylus with WordPress, it would be very nice to share some thoughs!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you mind sending us link to whole CSS? I would try to convert it.

Comment: Thank you very much in advance Mira! 
Now I've actually found that both, 2012 and 2010 WordPress themes compile ok, mut none of my premium themes from Elegant Themes or WooThemes.

http://jauza.fi/stylus/ here you can find two CSS-files to give a try.
I'm of course more interested in how to debug and compile any CSS to working Stylus (whether the syntax is in CSS or not), than just finding out what the specific problem was with those files.
Thanks again!

Comment: Try to use this one tool. It seems working. http://css2stylus.com/

Comment: If you copy-paste all the CSS from http://jauza.fi/stylus/style.css or http://jauza.fi/stylus/style2.css
to http://css2stylus.com/
And then copy-paste the generated stylus to your .styl -file, does it compile?

With me it unfortunately won't. Before css2stylus or after...

Comment: I don't know how .styl works but I believe that all you need to do is just to copy it to css2stylus.com then copy it from it to notepad for example and save it as style.styl

Comment: Ok yeah. .styl needs to be compiled to CSS to browsers can read it. It's just a way to write the rules faster and cannot be read by browser as such. And if the Stylus-syntax has bugs, it wont compile to CSS. And the problem is that many CSS -files made by others (i.e. Wordpress, Elegant Themes) won't compile and I'm having difficulties finding where the bugs are...

But still, thanks Mira!